# How to get argument value in custom validation attribute in .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

How can i access `myargument` value `argvalue` from `ValidateMain`

**Model**

```
[ValidateMain]
public class MainClass
{
    [ValidateChild(myargument: "argvalue")]
    public string myproperty { get; set; }

    [ValidateChild(myargument: "argvalue2")]        
    public string myproperty2 { get; set; }

}
```

**ValidationAttributes**

```
public class ValidateChild : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string myargument;

    public ValidateChild(string myargument)
    {
        this.myargument = myargument;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Here I know how to get myargument value. My problem is how to get it in ValidateMain
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}

public class ValidateMain : ValidationAttribute
{
    public ValidateMain()
    {

    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo item in value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            // What I need here is to get 'myargument' value 'argvalue'
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below statement to get its value:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo item in value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var x = item.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault().ConstructorArguments.FirstOrDefault();

        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

Debug and have a quick watch then you can find out how to get it

Comment: Great! One more tiny question if you wouldn't mind. Can I get value directly using `myargument` variable name or do I have to go through with index numbers?